# ReportViewer RDLC - Azure Websites Error 80004005

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I hope someone can help me with this. It's killing me. I've spent hours over days on it and my client is becoming increasingly frustrated. :(

I am hosting on Azure Websites and SQL Azure. I am using v.10 of the Reporting assemblies. Everything works perfectly fine outside of Azure (localhost, no problems)

I have a ReportViewer in ASP.NET within a user control. The ReportViewer and RDLC are working perfectly for display and export to Excel/Word, however I am having issues with PDF export and printing within IE.

**When printing:**

> Prompt: An error occurred during printing. (0x80004005)

and

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   Trident/5.0; SLCC2;     .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET
>   CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3) Timestamp: Wed, 24 Apr
>   2013 03:18:56 UTC
>
> Message: Unspecified error. Line: 1058 Char: 13 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://XXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=10.0.40219.329&Name=ViewerScript

Line 1058 of that .axd is:

> printObj.Print(printInfo.PrintRequestPath, printInfo.PrintRequestQuery, printInfo.ReportDisplayName);

**When exporting to PDF:**

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parameter is not valid.  Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.]
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.GetHdc() +1143305
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.RichText.LineBreaker.Flow(TextBox
>   textBox, Graphics g, FontCache fontCache, FlowContext flowContext,
>   Boolean keepLines, Single& height) +57
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.RichText.TextBox.MeasureFullHeight(TextBox
>   textBox, Graphics g, FontCache fontCache, FlowContext flowContext,
>   Single& contentHeight) +500
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.TextBox.DetermineVerticalSize(PageContext
>   pageContext, Double topInParentSystem, Double bottomInParentSystem,
>   List`1 ancestors, Boolean& anyAncestorHasKT, Boolean
>   hasUnpinnedAncestors) +381
>
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.PageItem.CalculateVertical(PageContext
>   pageContext, Double topInParentSystem, Double bottomInParentSystem,
>   PageItem[] siblings, List`1 ancestors, Boolean& anyAncestorHasKT,
>   Boolean hasUnpinnedAncestors, Nullable`1 sourceWidth) +695
>
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.RowInfo.CalculateVerticalLastDetailCell(PageContext
>   context, Boolean firstTouch, Boolean delayCalc) +411
>
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.Tablix.CreateDetailCell(Tablix
>   tablix, TablixMember colMemberParent, Int32 colGridIndex, RowInfo
>   rowInfo, PageContext pageContext) +822
>
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.Tablix.TraverseColumnMembers(Tablix
>   tablix, TablixMember colMemberParent, Int32 parentColIndex, RowInfo
>   currRowInfo, Boolean create, Double startInTablix, Double endInTablix,
>   Int32& detailCellIndex, Int32& visibleSpan, List`1 detailCellsState,
>   PageContext pageContext) +108
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.Tablix.TraverseColumnMembers(Tablix
>   tablix, TablixMember colMemberParent, Int32 parentColIndex, RowInfo
>   currRowInfo, Boolean create, Double startInTablix, Double endInTablix,
>   Int32& detailCellIndex, Int32& visibleSpan, List`1 detailCellsState,
>   PageContext pageContext) +869
>
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.Tablix.CreateDetailRow(Tablix
>   tablix, TablixMember rowMemberParent, Int32 parentRowIndex, Int32
>   parentColIndex, PageContext pageContext) +292
>
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.Tablix.CreateRowMemberChildren(Tablix
>   tablix, TablixMember rowMemberParent, Int32 defTreeLevel, Boolean
>   parentBorderHeader, Int32 parentRowIndex, Int32 parentColIndex, Int32
>   sourceIndex, Boolean resetContext, Boolean parentHasFooters, LevelInfo
>   parentLevelInfo, PageContext pageContext) +137
>
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.Tablix.CreateRowMemberChildren(Tablix
>   tablix, TablixMember rowMemberParent, Int32 defTreeLevel, Boolean
>   parentBorderHeader, Int32 parentRowIndex, Int32 parentColIndex, Int32
>   sourceIndex, Boolean resetContext, Boolean parentHasFooters, LevelInfo
>   parentLevelInfo, PageContext pageContext) +2822
>
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.Tablix.CreateRowMemberChildren(Tablix
>   tablix, TablixMember rowMemberParent, Int32 defTreeLevel, Boolean
>   parentBorderHeader, Int32 parentRowIndex, Int32 parentColIndex, Int32
>   sourceIndex, Boolean resetContext, Boolean parentHasFooters, LevelInfo
>   parentLevelInfo, PageContext pageContext) +2822
>
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.Tablix.CreateRowMemberChildren(Tablix
>   tablix, TablixMember rowMemberParent, Int32 defTreeLevel, Boolean
>   parentBorderHeader, Int32 parentRowIndex, Int32 parentColIndex, Int32
>   sourceIndex, Boolean resetContext, Boolean parentHasFooters, LevelInfo
>   parentLevelInfo, PageContext pageContext) +2822
>
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.Tablix.CreateTablixRows(Tablix
>   tablix, TablixMember rowMemberParent, Int32 defTreeLevel, Boolean
>   parentBorderHeader, Int32 parentRowIndex, Int32 parentColIndex,
>   List`1& pageStructMemberCell, Boolean ignoreTotals, Boolean&
>   finishLevel, Boolean parentHasFooters, CreateItemsContext createItems,
>   Double startInTablix, Double endInTablix, PageContext pageContext)
>   +2310    Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.Tablix.CreateTablixItems(Tablix
>   tablix, PageContext pageContext, CreateItemsContext createItems,
>   Double startInTablix, Double endInTablix) +113
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.Tablix.CreateVertically(PageContext
>   pageContext, CreateItemsContext createItems, Double startInTablix,
>   Double endInTablix, Double topInParentSystem) +286
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.Tablix.DetermineVerticalSize(PageContext
>   pageContext, Double topInParentSystem, Double bottomInParentSystem,
>   List`1 ancestors, Boolean& anyAncestorHasKT, Boolean
>   hasUnpinnedAncestors) +646
>
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.PageItem.CalculateVertical(PageContext
>   pageContext, Double topInParentSystem, Double bottomInParentSystem,
>   PageItem[] siblings, List`1 ancestors, Boolean& anyAncestorHasKT,
>   Boolean hasUnpinnedAncestors, Nullable`1 sourceWidth) +695
>
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.PageItemContainer.DetermineContentVerticalSize(PageContext
>   pageContext, Double topInParentSystem, Double bottomInParentSystem,
>   List`1 ancestors, Boolean& anyAncestorHasKT, Boolean
>   hasUnpinnedAncestors, Boolean resolveState, Boolean resolveItem) +273 
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.PageItemContainer.DetermineVerticalSize(PageContext
>   pageContext, Double topInParentSystem, Double bottomInParentSystem,
>   List`1 ancestors, Boolean& anyAncestorHasKT, Boolean
>   hasUnpinnedAncestors) +145
>
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.PageItem.CalculateVertical(PageContext
>   pageContext, Double topInParentSystem, Double bottomInParentSystem,
>   PageItem[] siblings, List`1 ancestors, Boolean& anyAncestorHasKT,
>   Boolean hasUnpinnedAncestors, Nullable`1 sourceWidth) +695
>
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.PageItem.CalculateVertical(PageContext
>   pageContext, Double topInParentSystem, Double bottomInParentSystem,
>   PageItem[] siblings, List`1 ancestors, Boolean& anyAncestorHasKT,
>   Boolean hasUnpinnedAncestors) +53
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.Report.NextPage(RPLWriter
>   rplWriter, Int32 page, Int32 totalPages) +659
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.HPBProcessing.NextPage()
>   +52    Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.HPBProcessing.Init(Report
>   report, PaginationSettings pagination, CreateAndRegisterStream
>   createAndRegisterStream, Hashtable& renderProperties) +348
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.PDFRenderer.Render(Report
>   report, NameValueCollection deviceInfo, Hashtable renderProperties,
>   CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStream) +141
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.RendererBase.Render(Report
>   report, NameValueCollection reportServerParameters,
>   NameValueCollection deviceInfo, NameValueCollection
>   clientCapabilities, Hashtable& renderProperties,
>   CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStream) +61
>
> [LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report
>   processing.]
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format,
>   Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode
>   pageCountMode, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback,
>   Warning[]& warnings) +333
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalModeSession.RenderReport(String
>   format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo,
>   NameValueCollection additionalParams, Boolean
>   cacheSecondaryStreamsForHtml, String& mimeType, String&
>   fileNameExtension) +215
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ExportOperation.PerformOperation(NameValueCollection
>   urlQuery, HttpResponse response) +154
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context) +216
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +341    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

Thank you.

Comment: I think you should focus on the `[LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing.]` portion. I've not used this mode myself but it almost sounds like you're including your report file in your ASP.NET solution but it's not being deployed to the server. Is this the case? And if so, what's the copy/build settings for this file in Solution Explorer/Properties?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It's possible I'm missing a .dll but can't imagine what it might be. I'm including all the reporting assemblies. Also, the reports display and export to Word/Excel without a problem. They just don't work with the IE-only print option, nor will they export to PDF from the ReportViewer.
EDIT: I should add that the .rdlc files are being deployed and have verified that via FTP.

Comment: See also https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b4a6eb43-0013-435f-9d11-00ee26a8d017/report-viewer-error-on-export-pdf-or-excel-from-azure-web-sites?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDF generation is actually not supported in the security configuration on WAWS, in this case you should use either a WebRole or a Web Server on a Virtual Machine.
Thanks!
Nir (WAWS team)

Comment: Thank you so much Nir for the reply. I know you say it's "Not supported" but is it accurate to say that it's the reason for the errors I'm seeing? I figured it might be a permissions or security issue of some sort but can't seem to find much information online.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer since it seems to be the only information I can get on the subject.

Comment: I'd like to comment here for anyone coming across this in the future. This is, in fact, the correct answer. I've since migrated this application to a web role and everything is working. There is no access to the required GDI+ assemblies in a Windows Azure Website. These resources are available within a Web or Worker role.

Comment: A Basic or Standard Website will support it now as well.

Answer (score 4):

I got same issue today when I was publishing to Azure Web Site(App). Problem was solved by migrating site from FREE to BASIC app service plan tier.

Comment: Thank you @marc! This seems to be the correct answer as at June 2017!

Answer (score 0):

one more possibility could be the missing `dlls` on the cloud.
For reporting, as you have referenced the `Microsoft.Reporting.Webforms` dll which gets locally stored on your local drive and doesn't gets packaged when you deploy your application on the cloud. So, we are suppose to also copy/upload/deploy these `dlls` too on cloud.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/b4a6eb43-0013-435f-9d11-00ee26a8d017